# How can I detect which device initiated the touch event in Kivy? e.g. finger, pen, or mouse

Tags: kivy

I'm trying to create a program that needs to differntiate between Kivy touch events originating from touching the touchscreen with a finger, a pen, or using the mouse/touchpad. Kivy is new to me.

Going through the touch event API documentation, I saw there are properties like `touch.profile` or `touch.uid`, or others. I'm not sure which to pick up. It seems that every property I tried don't return a unique device id so I can determine which of the three "devices" I mentioned caused the event.

Also worth mentioning is that in the Kivy initialization output text I see:

```
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event9
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event9>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event5
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event5>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[WARNING] [MTD         ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event9". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
[WARNING] [MTD         ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event5". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
```

However, my pen and finger-touch work nonetheless. [Xournal++](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp) on my Linux machine works well with pen and finger so I don't think it's a user permissions problem.

The output of `print(touch.device)` for example, yields `mouse` in all three cases.

I'm on Linux but intend to have this supported *at least* on Windows as well. Also found https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.input.providers.mtdev.html and https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.input.providers.probesysfs.html#module-kivy.input.providers.probesysfs but am not sure what to do with this information or if it's relevant, as I understood that providers are detected automatically.

Kivy alternatives are also welcome, though it seems like a really nice framework so I'd rather stick with it. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Does `print(type(touch))` yield the same for all three?

Comment: Yeah, all are `MouseMotionEvent`, but good idea to check!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what Xournal++ uses to access the devices, but simply adding yourself to the `input` group (and rebooting) fixed it for me and way safer than running as root:

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER input
```

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem and solved it using root. I use Ubuntu so used:

```
    sudo su
```

Worked like a charm!
All the best buddy!

Comment: I prefer not to run every app using sudo. It is not safe!